# rails undefined method 'has_many'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rake, migrate

I'm making a database:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    has_many :listings, :dependent => :restrict #won't delete if listings exist
    has_many :transactions, :dependent => :restrict #won't del if trans exist
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.integer :key #it's hard to use string as primary
      t.string :identifier_url
      t.string :username
      t.integer :rating

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
class CreateListings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    has_one :book
    belongs_to :transaction
    belongs_to :user
    create_table :listings do |t|
      t.integer :key
      t.integer :condition
      t.decimal :price

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I can't find anything anywhere on this so I'm guessing it's something really basic.

Answer (score 2):

The associations (has_many, belongs_to etc...) should be declared in the model, not in the migration.

This is a good read to start with migrations:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

And this one for associations:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: but for using "belongs_to :user" in the model, there has to be a column user_id in the table ?!?

Comment: @Klaus, yes, of course. If you use generators to create the model that column will already be there for you

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to declare the associations in the migration, but in the models!

Answer (score 0):

Put your association in the model

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :listings, :dependent => :restrict 
has_many :transactions, :dependent => :restrict

end
```